# How to Space Arrays into even columns (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

For a project I am doing for school, I need to read 2 files, one with month values, and one with visitor data. Reading the files, putting them into arrays is easy, the hard part is spacing. Spacing the arrays is mainly a problem as I have no idea how to space values evenly when the strings, in this case, months of the year, are uneven. With months of the same length, such as June and July, the spacing stays fairly even and neat, the left justifying working, but with uneven month names, the columns begin to swerve and look ugly. Current state of code is shown below.

```
while (r < 12 && c < 5 && count < 13) { //while loop until the end of each is closed
    cout << setw(5) << visitor_data[r][c] << " " << setw(5) << left; //data, space out
    c++; //next column
    if (c % 5 == 0) { //ends line for each complete row of data
        r++; //next row
        cout << endl << setw(5); //ends line
        cout << months_do[count] << "  " << setw(3) << right;
        c = 0; //column zero
        count++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly are `left` and `right`? You could also just `cout << "\t\t"` between values. Lame, but it usually works.

Comment: You have 13 months?

Comment: @KillzoneKid For all intents and purposes, this still works for the function. Probably why I'm getting an fstream window prompt though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your set widths equal or exceed the maximum number of characters that will be printed. Your width before printing months is set at 5, but if you have the month 'december' spelled out entirely it will exceed the setw and could be causing your uneven columns. Hope this helps!